# Identifying class diagram classes from a use case specification?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I'm currently trying to learn the construction of class diagrams for an upcoming exam, although I'm having difficulties knowing how to identify classes based on a use case specification (or any similar description of a system).

I understand people here can be reluctant to help with education based questions, I just wanted to clarify that I'm not asking for the work to be done for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

I'm going over a past revision paper which contains a use case specification for the process of 'purchasing an ice cream' at a vending machine. The first question is to identify 9 typical classes from this specification.

I understand a class is like an object and usually identified by a noun, although my confusion is how I am able to extract 9 classes as I can only seem to find 6, that is if they're even correct:

Customer, Student, Staff, Touch Screen, Change Dispenser, and Member Card.

Here is the use case specification, apologies for the length:

> Ben & Jerry’s company has just installed a new vending machine at a
>   University; it has a variety of ice creams available, in the format of
>   tubs or mini-tubs of different flavours. Products are subsidised for
>   students and staff but not for the rest of users; such that a customer
>   can insert a member card in a card reader and the subsidised prize for
>   the selected ice cream is displayed. You have designed a use case
>   model of the system, and identified a single use case (“purchase an
>   ice cream”) where the main actors are the customers.
>
> - ID: VM1
> - Name: Purchase a tub
> - Main Actors:
>
>   1. Subsidised customer (staff and students)  2 Non-subsidised customer
> - Pre-conditions:
>
>   1. Machine is on and works perfectly fine
>   2. There is stock of drinks and coins
>   3. There is sufficient stock of coins in the machine for providing change
>   4. There is sufficient stock of products
> - Main Flow:
>
>   1. Machine displays a welcome message
>   2. Student/staff inserts member card
>   3. System validates member card
>   4. Customer selects the tub by pressing the touch screen
>   5. Machine displays the subsidised price for the selected ice cream
>   6. REPEAT until sufficient coins entered: 6.1 Customer enters coin 6.2 Touch screen displays the amount entered so far
>   7. System dispenses the tub
>   8. IF too many coins are entered change is delivered
>   9. Price is added to the weekly total amount
>   10. Machine resets
> - Post Condition: Ice cream purchased
> - Alternative flow 1:
>
>   6. IF customer does not have sufficient coins 6.1 Customer presses the return button 6.2 System returns the entered coins
> - Alternative flow 2:
>
>   3. IF validation is unsuccessful 3.1 Message informing user 3.2 Non-subsidised price is show 3.3 Use case continues main flow 4

If anybody can help I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have mostly identified a number of actors, few classes itself. To start your design, ask yourself what the system under consideration (SUC) is. Obviously a vending machine. Now look at the UC how this SUC acts. There are a couple of hints:

- control resources (temperature, ice cream, tubs, etc.),
- control collection of money,
- control dispension of ice cream.

For these you can create controller classes which look to the outside and act accordingly (read temp -> turn on cooling; count money -> start vending; etc.)

The vending process with customer interaction is probably even more complex (show offers, make selection, pricing, etc.)

As you already guessed, this is no tutorial point. However, those are the basic steps to start the design. You can go on and create sequence diagrams to verify collaboration between the single classes (lots of exceptions like: temp controller starting to yell when temp does go up too much).

Comment: Thanks for the response. So do all classes need to be things that control something? For example could I have 'vending controller' as a class which is doing things like counting the total, or validating the user's member card? What confuses me is that it asks for 9 classes, a very specific number, yet it seems like the number of classes would be open to different interpretations.

Comment: Yes, the number depends on the design. It's probably that you should "at least" come up with 9 classes. Each class has a certain responsibility. And where you draw the boundary is up to you/your design. Finalizing with a single "doItAll" class is possible, but not constructive...